# Angular 10, rxjs - looping on subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making multiple concurrent `DELETE` requests to an API, causing a DeadLock on the server side.

If I had a fixed number of deletions I could do something like this:

```js
myAPI.delete(id).subscribe(res => {
   myAPI.delete(id2).subscribe(res => {
      myAPI.delete(id3).subscribe(res => {
      })
   })
})
```

Waiting to the previous deletion to be succesfully completed before making a new one (secuential).

The problem is that I can have from `1` to `N` requests, so I'm looking for something similar to a `for` instruction on subscription.

Is there any elegant approach for solving this?

Comment: Can you try a recursive function?

Comment: Why would you send `1 to n` requests but rather sending all  `1...N` parameters to `server`and handle it there

Comment: @BasheerKharoti you are right, but its an external API that I have no control over

Comment: This is a poor API design. You should be doing this server side.

Comment: @Iñigo agreed with Adrian Brand you should pass all IDs to server and then perform all delete operations there instead of making multiple delete calls from front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple methods.

#### Sequential requests

You could use the RxJS [`range`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/range) operator with mapping operator [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) to call each request sequentially.

```js
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs';

range(1, N).pipe(                      // <-- will emit 1-N numbers
  concatMap(id => myAPI.delete(id))    // <-- set the correct `id` for each request here
).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.log(err),
);
```

Since we're using `concatMap` operator, the request for each `id` will wait before the previous request is complete.

You could also use other mapping operators like `switchMap`, `flatMap` and `exhaustMap` for different behaviors. Difference b/n them [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/).

---

### Other methods - Parallel requests

#### Complete parallel requests

You could make multiple concurrent calls using the RxJS [`toArray`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/toArray) and  [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) operators. It subscribes to multiple observables *simultaneously*.

```js
import { range, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, N).pipe(                      // <-- will emit 1-N numbers
  concatMap(id => myAPI.delete(id)),   // <-- set the correct `id` for each request here
  toArray(),                           // <-- buffer all notifications and emit once as an array
  concatMap(reqs => forkJoin(reqs))
).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.log(err),
);
```

#### Buffered parallel requests

Most browsers have a hard limit on number of maximum parallel requests to a single domain (eg. Chrome - 6). If you run into this issue you could use RxJS [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) operator instead of the `toArray` operator to control the max number of parallel requests.

```js
import { from, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, bufferCount } from 'rxjs';

range(1, N).pipe(                      // <-- will emit 1-N numbers
  concatMap(id => myAPI.delete(id)),   // <-- set the correct `id` for each request here
  bufferCount(6),                      // <-- adjust number of parallel requests here
  concatMap(reqs => forkJoin(reqs))
).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.log(err),
);
```

Comment: But if they are simultaneous requests the server will be overloaded anyway, not solving the deadlocking issue, right? I was trying to make the requests sequential

Comment: @Iñigo: I've updated the answer to include complete sequential requests.

Comment: I advise editing this answer to only include the `concatMap` solution, as it is the only one which provides the requested behaviour, i.e. sequential requests

Comment: @WillAlexander: Good point, but instead of outright removing the other answers, I've bumped the sequential solution to the top and other solutions to the bottom. This way people have access to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an array of ids that need to be removed, you can use the `from` operator in combination with `concatMap` and `toArray`. The last one is to only call the subscribe listener after all have been completed:

```
const ids = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

from(ids).pipe(
  concatMap((id) => deleteThis(id)),
  toArray()
).subscribe(() => {
   console.log('all deleted');
})
```

[working stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pdgeux?devtoolsheight=60) with mock request observable

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution is to use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) operator:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

concat(
   ...[1, 2, 3].map(id => this.delete(id)),
)
.pipe(toArray())
.subscribe(() => console.log('all deleted'))
```

or without `toArray()` operator:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

concat(...[1, 2, 3].map(id => this.delete(id)))
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log('one deleted')
    },
    err => {},
    () => {
      console.log('all deleted')
    })
```

Comment: don't forget the `toArray()` :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const N = 10;
range(1, N)
  .pipe(concatMap(deleteById), ignoreElements())
  .subscribe({
      complete: () => console.log('Complete')
  });

function deleteById(id: number): Observable<String> {
  return of(`deleted-${id}`).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

If you want make multiple request same time:

```js
const N = 10;
const CHUNKED = 3; // (3 requests same time) concat (3 requests same time) ...

range(1, N)
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(CHUNKED),
    concatMap((ids) => forkJoin(ids.map(deleteById))),
    ignoreElements()
  )
  .subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log(`Complete`)
  });
```